# MobileFirst Development Server is showing the deployed projects in double?

Tags: eclipse, worklight-server, mobilefirst-server

I'm using MobileFirst (Worklight 7.1) and it's showing the deployed projects in double in the Eclipse server view. Is that normal? can anyone explain this for me please?

Here a screenshot of what I'm facing:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue that is scheduled to be fixed.
It's simply a "ghost" .war and can be ignored.